# How to format the output in a better way for geeksforgeeks problems

Tags: python

```
def doorcheck(n):

    doors = []
    for i in range(n):
        doors.append(False)

    for i in range(n):
        for x in range(n):
            if (x+1) % (i+1) == 0:
                if(doors[x] is False):
                    doors[x] = 1
                else:
                    doors[x] = 0
    for i in range(n-1):
        print(doors[i], end = ' ')
    print(doors[n-1], end = '\n')

t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    doorcheck(n)
```

Here I am trying to print each desired output in a separate line.
As asked in the question

```
Example:
Input:
2
3
5
Output:
1 0 0
1 0 0 1 0
```

And I have used

```
for i in range(n-1):
    print(doors[i], end = ' ')
print(doors[n-1], end = '\n')
```

the above code for this purpose. Is there a better way to do it?

Edit 1: The code above I wrote has a bug. But anyways @Barmar has given an excellent solution to my problem, which was about formatting output in a concise manner. And he also gave a suggestion for initializing an array which contains same element throughout its length. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to convert numbers into bitwise operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to print the elements of `doors` separated by spaces, use `join()`

```
print(' '.join(map(str, doors)))
```

You can also replace the loop that initializes `doors` with:

```
doors = [False] * n
```